# Understanding a Ternary Statement

Tags: php, ternary

I'm ready thought some old code and have come across this :

```
$sal = isset($_REQUEST['c_sal']) ? " " : ($_REQUEST['sal'] ? (Valid($_REQUEST['sal']) ? $_REQUEST['sal'] : false) : null);
```

I'm trying to work out what it does.
I know it's doing some form of validation at one point.. but how do I revert this back to a simple if elseif statement ?

So I can understand exactly what it's doing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following ternary operation

```
$sal = isset($_REQUEST['c_sal']) ? " " : ($_REQUEST['sal'] ? (Valid($_REQUEST['sal']) ? $_REQUEST['sal'] : false) : null);
```

Is the same as the following if statement:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['c_sal'])){
    $sal = " ";
} else {
    if($_REQUEST['sal']){
        if(Valid($_REQUEST['sal'])){
             $sal = $__REQUEST['sal'];
        else {
             $sal = false;
        }
    } else {
        $sal = null;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** For your info. The ternary without your function:

```
$sal = isset($_REQUEST['c_sal']) ? " " : (isset($_REQUEST['sal']) ? $_REQUEST['sal'] : null);
```

Comment: Thanks - That make sense. if I want to take the Valid statement out of this and then revert it back to ternary can that be done ?

Comment: `$sal = isset($_REQUEST['c_sal']) ? " " : ($_REQUEST['sal'] ? $_REQUEST['sal'] : null);`  Does that look about right ?

I didn't want to just do it, I wanted to understand what it was doing as well.

Comment: That isn't valid, and you aren't using your `Valid()` function anywhere.

Comment: I don't need the valid function, I want that removed. What's wrong with the ternary I've posted ? Does that not do the same as the first with the valid statement removed ?

Comment: Oh I see, apologies. Did you edit it? It's fine except you'll want to check if `$_REQUEST['sal']` is set, not just whether it is false. See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Just split it up into the if/else equivalents:

```
$sal = null;

if (isset($_REQUEST['c_sal'])) {
  $sal = " ";
} else {
 if ($_REQUEST['sal']) {
   if (Valid($_REQUEST['sal'])) {
     $sal = $_REQUEST['sal'];
   } else {
     $sal = false;
   }
  } else {
    $sal = null;
  }
}
```